# Querying Active Directory user information using Powershell - seemingly equivalent syntax, different results?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, sid

I have a simple Powershell function to perform an Active Directory LDAP lookup based on the SID of a user:

```
function SidToAdUser($sid) {[adsi]("LDAP://<SID=" + $sid + ">")}
```

If I wish to read an attribute from the returned User object, accessing it via an intermediary variable works fine:

```
$ad = SidToAdUser("S-1-5-21-968173855-142910291-87512543-670313")
$ad.department
```

However, attempting to access it directly from the return value of the function, like this:

```
SidToAdUser("S-1-5-21-968173855-142910291-87512543-670313").department
```

elicits an error:

```
format-default : The following exception occurred while retrieving member "distinguishedName": "An invalid dn syntax has been specified.
"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

Can anyone advise why exactly this would be the case, and how to correct it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function call syntax is wrong.

```
(SidToAdUser S-1-5-21-968173855-142910291-87512543-670313).department
```

In powershell, function arguments are specified as space-separated values after the function name, not enclosed in parens.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that by writing SidToAdUser("S-1-5-21-968173855-142910291-87512543-670313").department it is essentially being parsed as SidToAdUser ("S-1-5-21-968173855-142910291-87512543-670313").department?

Comment: I'd have to test that to see exactly how it got parsed.